# R ggplot extend the range of a category x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a dataframe similar to that below

```
a=data.frame(year=paste('FY',2001:2012,sep='.'),values=rnorm(12))
library(ggplot2)
```

The following graph works

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+geom_line()
```

but the following one does not.

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+geom_line() +xlim(0,13)
```

How can I extend the limits of a ggplot of data that has a category axis rather than a numeric one?

Comment: What do you want the plot to look like? What would the labels be for the x axis?

Comment: Hi @alexwhan the labels would be FY2001 through FY2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_discrete` and the `limits` parameter to add extra levels by `c`ombining these with your original levels:

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+
       geom_line() + 
       scale_x_discrete(limits=c(levels(a$year),"FY.2013"))
```

Comment: Sorry both. Had missed the fact I hadn't accepted on this one thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new factor with NA to extend the x-range. It is a little bit tricky but it does the job. I hope someone else get better solution.

```
b=data.frame(year=paste('FY',2013,sep='.'),
               values=NA)
a <- rbind(a,b)
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @agstudy. Thanks that definitely works. I'll wait and see if there is a more direct and programmatic answer if not I'll mark this up.